# Modport not accessible when interface instantiated with array

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

When interface is instantiated normally modports are accessible

eg:

```
interface intf1;
    reg a3, c3;
    modport mp3 (output a3, c3);
    assign c3 = a3;
endinterface

interface intf2(intf1.mp3 p2);
assign p2.a3 = 1'b1; // access to modports available
endinterface

module top(input din,output reg dout);
assign dout = din;
    intf1 INTF1 ();
    intf2 INTF2 (INTF1);
endmodule
```

but when inerface is intantiated with array, I could not access modports in interface intf2, Is there a way to access moports for multi instance interfaes in intf2?

```
interface intf1;
    reg a3, c3;
    modport mp3 (output a3, c3);
    assign c3 = a3;
endinterface

interface intf2(intf1.mp3 p2[3]);
//assign p2[3].a3 = 1'b1; // compiler reports Invalid bounds count
endinterface

module top(input din,output reg dout);
assign dout = din;
    intf1 INTF1 [3:1] ();
    intf2 INTF2 (INTF1);
endmodule
```

Comment: Does `p2[2].a3` work? I'd guess the elements are indexed from 0 to 2.

Comment: Could not use p2[2] or p2[1] errors out as invalid initialization

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation of the current standard. See http://www.eda.org/svdb/view.php?id=2975

My suggestion is not to use modports. If you must use them for synthesis, then you can't use them with an array of interfaces

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
     interface intf2(intf1.mp3 p2[3]);
       assign p2[0].a3 = 1'b1;
       assign p2[1].a3 = 1'b1;
       assign p2[2].a3 = 1'b1; // compiler reports Invalid bounds count
     endinterface
```

Also check the link below. Now it seems to be working correctly.

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/PJ7